# Create a custom view using a p:schedule

Tags: jsf, primefaces, schedule

Hi is it possible to create something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ4pm.png) with [`<p:schedule>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/schedule.xhtml)?

[image]
This view represents room booking where the line on top represents list of rooms. This view shows which room is available on what time, making in much more clear than the standard view.
Instead of event title I use drop down list of rooms. These rooms should be displayed in the top line.

Comment: Just to remind, you can make very little changes in the event labels by using HTML entities. For example: `eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Birthday Party \n NEW LINE DATA..", today1Pm(), today6Pm()));`

Answer (score 2):

No this is not possible. PrimeFaces uses jQuery `FullCalendar` so please check out [its documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/) on how to customize it and if it is possible at all.

But even if you can customize it, it is not certain that you can also use the same procedure to manipulate a PrimeFaces component.

Comment: My first guess was that the table I posted is same element as PrimeFaces <p:schedule> they even look the same. So my question is, how did they do it ? Or what tool would you recommend to create this ?

Comment: A little googling: http://embed.plnkr.co/cX9dH8eTjKaddJ0Gpw21/preview and http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/

Comment: Thank you I found that too, although since I'm already using primefaces I'd rather edit p:schedule instead of using edited jQuery fullcalendar. So now I'm searching on how to use above mentioned fullcalendar update in p:schedule. I'm hoping its possible when even PrimeFaces uses jQuery FullCalendar.

Comment: I hope you succeed. Having a resources view would be interesting. But you might need to tweak the PrimeFaces `Schedule.java` `ScheduleRenderer.java` and the .js wrapper to

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find anyone who's done this with primefaces. And the fullcalendar.js and fullcalendar.css that jQuery uses for fullcalendar isn't the same thing as schedule.js and schedule.css that primefaces uses for schedule. So the only way for me to do this is that I find somebody who's edited schedule.js and schedule.css in the same way as fullcalendar was edited.